# Updating related data EF Database first

Tags: entity-framework, generics

This is my first time updating related data of a table on EF.

```
var _agent = _unitOfWork.AgentsRepository.GetByID(agent.AgentId);
_agent.map_Agent_Language = new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<map_Agent_Language>();
var numlist = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5};

foreach (var item in numlist)
{
   _agent.map_Agent_Language.Add(new map_Agent_Language() { AgentLanguageId = 0, AgentId = agent.AgentId, LanguageId = Convert.ToInt32(item) });
}

_unitOfWork.AgentsRepository.Update(_agent);
int result = _unitOfWork.Save();

return (result > 0);
```

These are the method used.

```
        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public int Save()
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

EDIT:

This code inserts data on table map_agent_language instead of deleting old datas before inserting a new one.

How can i force EF to delete it first before inserting?

tnx..

ps Is there a better way in updating related datas on db first? thanks

Comment: Check if AgentId you passing is not null. And if its not null then check that it should be identity column and in that case you should not pass it.

Comment: @GirishSakhare hi kindly check my edited question tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should get the old data first by AgentID and only add the required new data and delete unwanted data

Example

```
 repo.GetQuery().Where(r => r.AgentId == AgentId && !numlist .Contains(r.LanguageId )).Delete();
```

Then add

```
  foreach (int item in numlist)
   {
    if (!existing.Contains(item ))
            {
                var toAdd = new map_Agent_Language
                {
                   ... The properties to set
                };

                repo.AddObject(toAdd);
            }
        }
        repo.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What is that Get query? BTW i'm using DBcontext

Comment: You can ignore that part you can write in your convenient way to fetch the existing records and delete the unwanted and add the missing.

Comment: thank you for giving me an idea. I extended our generics repository then added database transact for deleting related datas before updating Agent Info!